# Generation of antialiased transparent png images with php

Tags: php, tags, transparency, antialiasing

I've read many artikles about generating transparent images but still have a problem with the transparency. First of all here is my code:

```
<?php
$text = 'I feel dirty with those borders';
$color = array( 255, 128, 0);
$font = 'arial.ttf';
$size = 44;

// Create the image
$testImg = imagecreatetruecolor(20, 20);
$testCol = imagecolorallocate($testImg, $color[0], $color[1], $color[2]);
$rect = imagettftext($testImg, $size, 0, 0, 0, $testCol, $font, $text);
$width = $rect[4] - $rect[0] + 2;
$height = $rect[1] - $rect[5];
$yOffset = -$rect[5];

imagedestroy($testImg);

$img = imagecreatetruecolor( $width, $height);
imageantialias ( $img, true);
$black = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0);
imagecolortransparent($img, $black);
$col = imagecolorallocate($img, $color[0], $color[1], $color[2]);
$rect = imagettftext($img, $size, 0, -1, $yOffset, $col, $font, $text);
imagepng($img, "test.png");
imagedestroy($img);

?>
<html>
<body bgcolor="ffFFa0">
<img src="test.png" />
</body>
</html>
```

If I generate an image with this code I get black borders around the text where the colour of the letters is not totally opaque or completely transparent. I think the reason is that only the pixels which are exactly 100% black are transparent. But what other way is there? I also tried to use alphablending with no success.

Can anybody give me a hint or a link to a good example?

Thanks in advance

parascus

Comment: I found the answer by chance after searching a while at stackoverflow. Because I don't know how to link to this answer or to comment the other I want to note that in the question "Can PNG image transparency be preserved when using PHP's GDlib imagecopyresampled?" (32243) the note of Jorrit Schippers gave me the track to my solution which I describe under neath. Thanks a lot!

Comment: $border = imagecreatefrompng( "b.png");
$outX = 120;
$outY = 180;
$other = imagecreatefromjpeg( "b.jpg");
$inX = 100;
$inY = 150;

$dst = imagecreatetruecolor( $outX, $outY);
imagealphablending( $dst, false);
$color = imagecolorallocatealpha ( $dst , 0, 0, 0, 127 );
imagefill ( $dst , 0 , 0 , $color );
imagealphablending( $dst, true);
imagecopy ( $dst, $tutor, ($outX-$inX)/2, ($outY-$inY)/2, 0, 0, $inX, $inY);
imagecopy ( $dst, $border, 0, 0, 0, 0, $outX, $outY);

imagesavealpha( $dst, true);
imagepng(  $dst, 'out.png', 9 );